# how i can get 'argc' and 'argv' from main function to QGLWidget

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qtcore, qcoreapplication

I have a class QGLWidget in my project, this is a opengl class, and in the class i use  'argc' and 'argv'  attributes of the class main.
but i can not get pass these attributes to the my class, there is some method for this?

this the part of constructor of my class using the argv and argc attributes :

```
VideoOpenGL::VideoOpenGL(QWidget *parent) :
    QGLWidget(parent)
{

    XnStatus nRetVal = XN_STATUS_OK;

    if (argc > 1)
    {
        nRetVal = g_Context.Init();
        //CHECK_RC(nRetVal, "Init");
        nRetVal = g_Context.OpenFileRecording(argv[1], g_Player);
        if (nRetVal != XN_STATUS_OK)
        {
            printf("Can't open recording %s: %s\n", argv[1], xnGetStatusString(nRetVal));
            return;
        }
    }
```

and my head file:

```
class VideoOpenGL : public QGLWidget
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit VideoOpenGL(QWidget *parent = 0);
        //explicit VideoOpenGL( int & argc, char ** argv );
        //void set_mainAtribs(const int & argc, char **argv);


    protected:
        //const int argc;
        //char **argv;

        // /*
        void initializeGL();
        //void resizeGL(int w, int h);
        //void paintGL();
        static void glutKeyboard (unsigned char key, int /*x*/, int /*y*/);
        static void glutDisplay(void);
        static void glutIdle (void);
        void CleanupExit();
        void LoadCalibration();
        void SaveCalibration();
      // */
    signals:

    public slots:

    };
```

Comment: What's the problem with `set_mainAtribs(int argc, char **argv)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have different ways to achieve depending on more precise context you have not yet provided.

I will assume you are using a Qt application. If not, try to use a setter for the class which gets set directly or indirectly from the main function.

If you use a Qt application, [you could initialize the application object](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qapplication.html#QApplication) with the main function's arguments, and then you can access it anywhere by the [static arguments() method](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#arguments).

You will also need to convert the QString returned to QByteArray with the toUtf8() method and then with data() to char *, i.e.:

```
arguments.at(1).toUtf8().data()
```

Alternatively, which is probably even better, you can use [the qPrintable() function](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qPrintable). I will use this below.

```
qPrintable(arguments.at(1))
```

I will personally use qApp to access it, but you could use QCoreApplication::arguments(), too. I find the former also shorter and I am a lazy programmer for good. ;)

You could write something like this if you happen to use a Qt application:

#### main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    ...
    return a.exec();
}
```

#### videoopengl.cpp

```
VideoOpenGL::VideoOpenGL(QWidget *parent) :
    QGLWidget(parent)
{

    XnStatus nRetVal = XN_STATUS_OK;

    QStringList arguments = qApp->arguments();
    if (arguments.size() > 1)
    {
        nRetVal = g_Context.Init();
        //CHECK_RC(nRetVal, "Init");
        nRetVal = g_Context.OpenFileRecording(qPrintable(arguments.at(1)), g_Player);
        if (nRetVal != XN_STATUS_OK)
        {
            printf("Can't open recording %s: %s\n", qPrintable(arguments.at(1)), xnGetStatusString(nRetVal));
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thaks, but Now a have the error using the two line  arguments.at(1):
"error: cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type 'const class QString' through '...' printf("Can't open recording %s: %s\n", arguments.at(1), xnGetStatusString(nRetVal));"

and how i can make this code in class VideoOpenGL "glInit(&argc, argv)"?

                                                                                                ^

Comment: @user3651443: sorry, my code is wrong, try this: `arguments.at(1).toUtf8().data()`. arguments.at(1) returns a QString, and you need char* with "printf". I would personally use QTextStream or QDebug though, or at least stdout. Alternatively, which is probably even better, use `qPrintable(arguments.at(1))`.

Comment: thanks, it work, but i have more one question, how make this code glutInit(&argc, argv) ?

Comment: @user3651443: you could use qApp->arguments().size and qApp->arguments().toVector().data() or just pass argc and argv directly in the main, but I think it is not a good idea to mix to opengl wrapper libraries.

Answer (score 3):

You could always use the static [QCoreApplication::arguments()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#arguments) function from anywhere in your application.